# How to verify which index of a global array was accessed from another program?

Tags: arrays, linux, virtual-address-space

There is program running which has globally initialized large arrays. I want to verify which index of that large array is getting accessed from another program running in the same machine simultaneously.

I saw how to get a set of pages in the physical memory for a given process proc_id and I also saw how the physical memory of system can be accessed directly. But how to verify which block is getting accessed currently.

How to access the global data segment access pattern of another process is the question. If anyone can direct me to any code example or any api that has this functionality it would be helpful.

Comment: User programs run in virtual address space and know nothing about real memory access.

Comment: Yes but if you can get a handle to page table of the process you can know what is the virtual to physical mapping right?